Insert loopable video into another video using ffmpeg
I use this command to insert .mov video with alpha channel into background video. But alpha channel video is playing only one time. How should I use -loop command and can I use loop every 30 seconds?
ffmpeg -i "output_all.mp4" -i "logo\logovid.mov" -filter_complex "[1:v]scale=in_w/2:-2[over];[0:v][over]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-5:50" -codec:v:0 libx264 -b:v 3M "final\gotovo.mp4"


We may complete the time of logovid to 30 seconds, then loop it over using loop filter, and use the looped video as [over]:
ffmpeg -y -i "input.mp4" -i "logo\logovid.mov" -filter_complex "[1:v]scale=in_w/2:-2,format=rgba[logo];color=black@0:100x100:r=30:d=30,format=rgba[c];[c][logo]scale2ref[c0][logo0];[c0][logo0]overlay=repeatlast=0[logo1];[logo1]loop=-1:30000[over];[0:v][over]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-5:50:shortest=1" -codec:v libx264 -b:v 3M "final\gotovo.mp4"

For testing, download vecteezy_countdown-leader-movie-intro-graphic-saber-fire-transparent_16911493.mov from here, and rename to logovid.mov.
We may also use the following input.mp4 for testing:
ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=s=1920x1080:r=30:d=250 input.mp4

Explaining the stages:
First stage: Overlay logovid over transparent background (Set the duration of the transparent background to 30 seconds):
ffmpeg -y -i logo\logovid.mov -filter_complex "[0:v]format=rgba[logo];color=black@0:100x100:r=30:d=30,format=rgba[c];[c][logo]scale2ref[c0][logo0];[c0][logo0]overlay=repeatlast=0" -c:v prores -pix_fmt yuva444p10le test30sec.mov
The result is 10 seconds logovid followed by 20 seconds of transparent video.

Second stage: Loop the output of the first stage multiple times using loop filter:
ffmpeg -y -i logo\logovid.mov -filter_complex "[0:v]format=rgba[logo];color=black@0:100x100:r=30:d=30,format=rgba[c];[c][logo]scale2ref[c0][logo0];[c0][logo0]overlay=repeatlast=0[logo1];[logo1]loop=-1:30000" -t 250 -c:v prores -pix_fmt yuva444p10le test250sec.mov
The result is: 10sec,20sec,10sec,20sec,10sec,20sec...

Third stage: Use the output of the second stage as [over] (also apply the original scale filer):
ffmpeg -y -i "input.mp4" -i "logo\logovid.mov" -filter_complex "[1:v]scale=in_w/2:-2,format=rgba[logo];color=black@0:100x100:r=30:d=30,format=rgba[c];[c][logo]scale2ref[c0][logo0];[c0][logo0]overlay=repeatlast=0[logo1];[logo1]loop=-1:30000[over];[0:v][over]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-5:50:shortest=1" -codec:v libx264 -b:v 3M "final\gotovo.mp4"

Wouldn't it be easier to extend the alpha video using tpad in a separate command, and then stream_loop that in a command similar to the original?

doesn't work in ffmpeg version 7.0.2-3ubuntu1

thanks a lot it works!

Great... Please note that is not the simplest solution, and it's not working with new versions of FFmpeg.

@Gyan you are right. I forgot about tpad filter. I also think that the loop filter is problematic with FFmpeg 7.
